# Passing the ios variable value to javascript function in phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

How can I pass the variable value (which is initialised in app delegate) to the javascript function on index page load. I am using cordova phonegap.

Comment: I think you will need to build custom plugin.